# How many sets can be made with two natural numbers less than 100?

Tags: combinatorics

My task is this:

Suppose $x,y\in\mathbb{N}:x,y<100$. How many sets $M=\{x,y\}$ can be made?

This is a combinatorial problem, but I know almost nothing about it so I decided to write it out. We get: 
\begin{align}x=0,y=0,1\ldots&,99,\#M=100\\
x=1,y=0,1\ldots&,99,\#M=100\\
\vdots\\
x=99,y=0,1,\ldots&,99,\#M=100\end{align}

So it seems that the total number of sets $M$ is $100^2$, the same as the area of a square whose sides are $100$, but is it right?

Comment: Yes, except I don't know about the inclusion of zero in the natural numbers, I used to specify the set whenever it included zero. The logic is correct, otherwise.

Comment: A *set* does **not** contain duplicate elements (in opposed to a *multi-set*). So the answer is $\binom{100}{2}$ if $0\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\binom{99}{2}$ if $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @barakmanos: A set doesn't contain duplicate elements, but that does not mean that the set $\{x,x\}$ does not exist. It just means that $\{x,x\}=\{x\}$.

Comment: @celtschk: The title says "sets with two numbers"!!!

Comment: The book I'm working with defines $\mathbb{N}=0,1,2,\ldots$  sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @barakmanos: The title says "sets made with two natural numbers", not "sets made with two *different* natural numbers". Nothing indicates that the cardinality of the set has to be $2$.

Comment: That's right, the only restrictions are that they must be natural numbers and less than 100.

Answer (score 3):

Like you said, it's a combinatorial problem.

I prefer solving this kind of problem in a stepwise (one step at a time) manner.

So here, we suppose: $\{x, y \in\mathbb{Z_+}: x, y<100\}$

Step 1: Now we'll start with $x$

There are 100 numbers less than 100, thus we can fix $x$ in 100 ways

Step2: Second step is now to fix $y$

There are also 100 numbers less than 100. However since repetition of numbers are  not permitted in a set, it means the number chosen in $x$ must not be repeated in $y$ meaning we can fic $y$ in 99 ways

Step3: The third and final step is the combination proper

Since there are 100 ways to fixing $x$ and 99 ways to fixing $y$, then there are a total of $100×99$ ways

Note however that order isn't important in a set. That is ${1,2} $ is same with ${2,1} $ thus we have to divide the answer we got by two to prevent duplication:

$$\frac{100×99}{2} $$

That gives us: 4950 ways

Another way of solving this is simply using the combination formula:

$$^{100} \mathbb{C}_2$$

This gives:

$$\frac{100!}{2! (100-2)!}=4950$$